# Cannot click on input type = "radio" that is inside a HTML label?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cucumber-jvm

I have a problem where I cannot click on the input type = "radio" using the `id="same-supplier-no"`:

```
<label for="same-supplier-no" ng-class="{checked: !ctrl.energyModel.BillViewModel.SameSupplier}" class="">

  <input type="radio" id="same-supplier-no" name="same-supplier" ng-model="ctrl.energyModel.BillViewModel.SameSupplier" ng-value="false" ng-change="ctrl.sameSupplierValueChanged(); ctrl.analyticsProvider.sendVirtualPageView('SameSupplierNo')" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" value="false">

   <span></span>No

</label>
```

In Selenium when I do:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("same-supplier-no")).click();
```

it says that "element not visible". There are previous radio buttons in the HTML that have labels on it and they have ID's for the labels (this one does not). 
I just refer to the label id and click that instead and it works. But this one doesn't have an ID for the label and I want to avoid xpath usage, however, if I have no choice, then I will just select via xpath/css.

I have also tried via locator name i.e. By.className("same-supplier"); and using a For loop and if statement to store the input type=radio element, still doesn't work.

**Question is**: why can I not click the input type = "radio", why is in not visible to Selenium? Is it because it is nested inside a Label? If so, does anyone know how I can click it using the id or just getting to the element?

Thank you.

Note: I am using Java 7 for Selenium.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the chat conversation I could try some stuff on the website you are using. The `radio` never becomes visible. As a result of this it is impossible to use the `click()` method on it.

The `label` that contains this `radio` is visible however. This means you could just use `click()` on this label.

```java
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("label[for='same-supplier-no']")).click();
```

Or if you really want to find the element using the `radio` you could use `xpath`.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='same-supplier-no']/parent::label")).click();
```

Comment: or driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='answer radio-ticks']/label[2]")).click();

Comment: Thanks RemcoW, I am aware of that. I have been using labels for other radioButtons on the page. However, the question was why I couldn't get to the ID of the radioButtons. It seems like you've answered it. Correct me if i'm wrong: the radioButtons are not set to visible, thus when click() method is called on it, because the element is not set to visible, it cannot find it to click it, thus it fails. Both findElement that you have provided work. I was able to do it using xpath before but the 2nd findElement is very good. Can you explain the "::", it's reference to a CSS tag?

Comment: @DesignAndCode You are almost right. It can find the element even if it is not visible. The problem is that selenium can't click on it if it isn't visible. As for the `::`, what this does is let you give a specific `tag name` of the element you're looking for. In this case it will look for any element with the id `same-supplier-no` that has a `label` as a parent.

Comment: If you'd change the `label` to `div` for instance it would fail because there is no element with the id `same-supplier-no` that has a `div` as a parent. You could also replace the `label` with `*` which means it doesn't matter what the parent element is, just get it.

Comment: Selenium finds it but can't click on it because it is not set to visible? Is my understanding correct? EDIT: I get it. It just tells it to look for a parent. Is the "::" a CSS thing?

Comment: Yes you're right on that first part. With tagname I just mean the name of the element, so `label`, `div`, `body`, etc.. In selenium you can also do a find using the tagname.

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you RemcoW. This solution is very good. I'm using the 2nd locator xpath expression. However, i'm hesitant to mark this as correct because is there a way of getting to it via just the ID (bypassing the visiblity check on the click()) to click on the id itself?

Comment: @DesignAndCode The only way to do that would be using `JavascriptExecutor` like I mentioned in the chat.

Comment: Ah, I see. For that reason, I will mark this as the correct answer. Thank you RemcoW and @LeonBarkan. You both were great help.

Answer (score 0):

use action to click on the lable and after that use:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
                IWebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.XPath("//label[@for='same-supplier-no']"));
                actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink);
                actions.click();
                actions.perform();

driver.findElement(By.id("same-supplier-no")).click();
```

Comment: What do you mean use action to click on the label? You mean have two .click()? One for the label and then one for the id? But the user doesn't do two clicks?

Comment: it's hovering to label for element to be visible

Comment: I am going to try it now and post the results, how did you know it was the "hover" that made it not visible?

Comment: i suspect, radio button's are in containers and sometimes when you click on them the first thing that you not see is you doing focus on specific area

Comment: the action syntax in c#  so you may have a little diference in your code but the functions are the same.

Comment: Tried it, upto the actions.perform() it works (it hovers and clicks the button). However, when the "driver.findElement(By.id("same-supplier-no")).click();" is called, it errors "element not visible". It seems to not be holding the hover when it executes that line, equalling it to not be visible by selenium?

Comment: try: driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='same-supplier-no']")).click();

Comment: No, still can't find it?

Comment: Tried this: public Supplier_page clickNoForGasAndElectricitySuppliersCheckbox(){
     Actions action = new Actions(driver);
     action.moveToElement(NotFromSameSupplier_label).perform();

     driver.findElement(By.id("same-supplier-no")).click();
       
     return this;
    } - so no click() after perform, so it hovers essentially? Still doesn't work however.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115387/discussion-between-designandcode-and-leon-barkan).

Answer (score 0):

After you click on "find postcode" button, add below two line of code -

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='same-supplier-question']/div/div/label[2]/span"))));
```

This is has worked at my end...
You can change the xpath from absolute to relative....

Comment: Thanks Punkaaj. I already knew how to click() it via xpath, however, I wanted to know why I couldn't go direct to ID without using an xpath. Why was it not "visible" to selenium. @RemcoW answered this and his solution is much cleaner than having many child elements after the ID in the Xpath. Not great for maintainability of a framework.